# Using buffer in sqlite select statement android

Tags: android

i'm making select statement and it works fine
the problem is selecting more than thousands of records ate one and this cause the program too slow.
is there a possibility to select fifty by fifty and when select  the first fifty record show them then add the next fifty record to them.
how can i do that .
thanks in advance ...

Comment: +1 for a good question, seems interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Use LIMIT/OFFSET Clauses is selection statement

Comment: How can be we defined LIMIT for select query If we don't know how much record in database?

Comment: First find the count of results then execute the query in loop with appropriate limit and offset values

Comment: You should expand this answer a little more.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked on that but can give some idea reagarding that. You can use `AsynTask` here. In the `doingInbackground()` you can get the records and then you can call `publishProgress()` when 50 records are fetched and update the UI.

**UPDATE:**

You can use the `LIMIT/OFFSET` clause that Kiran said to get the limit of the record fetched and can update the UI using AsyncTask.

Comment: Interested in this line "is there a possibility to select fifty by fifty and when select the first fifty record show them then add the next fifty record to them".

Comment: Yes, that is some what more than the word "interesting". I don't know that is there a sql query or something that checks if 50 data are fetched or not.

Comment: Yes,for publish the some amount of records its nice but its more beautiful if "Using buffer in sqlite select statement android" line's answer achieved.

Comment: we can use limit/offset as kiran said in the above answer to find the records that are fetched and the update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need to back your AutoCompleteTextView with a cursor adapter.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    final AdapterHelper h = new AdapterHelper(this);


    Cursor c = h.getAllResults();
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] from = new String[] { "val" };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    CursorAdapter adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, c,
            from, to);

    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint == null) {
                return h.getAllResults();
            }
            String s = '%' + constraint.toString() + '%';
            return h.getAllResults(s);
        }
    });

    text.setAdapter(adapter);

}

class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    }

    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("val"));
    }

}
```

The database that I am using has 3k rows of data in it and the Autocomplete works fine.

The things to note are that you need make sure that the your adapter puts the correct value in the text box once a user selects it. Do this with the convertToString method (at the end of the snippet above). You get to this method by extending SimpleCursorAdapter and overriding the method as shown.

Then you need to provide a FilterQueryProvider to your adapter. This allows your query to be run with the where clause of your typed text. If you have a huge dataset, then setting the threshold large enough (either programatically, or in xml) will prevent the filter query running until it will return a suitably sized resultset.

Hope this is useful.

Anthony Nolan

Comment: NO i'm displaying the result in autoCompleteTextView

Comment: You probably need to set a cursor adapter on your autoCompleteTextView. This should achieve the same affect as I mentioned for ListView. The method to use is public void setAdapter (T adapter) on AutoCompleteTextView.